# puppeteer isn't working with my javascript code

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to test a very simple code but it's not working. It must be doing a very simple mistake but  I can't find the problem.
The code below runs with no errors but the browse does not open:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    console.log("1");
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

    console.log("2");
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    console.log("3");
    await page.goto('https://google.com/');

    console.log("4");
    await page.waitForSelector('#fakebox-input');

    console.log("5");
    await browser.close;

});
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: It's almost a complete copy of example from https://pptr.dev/ it should work at leat untill `waitForSelector`

Comment: You need to **call** the async function `(async () => {})();`

Comment: @hardkoded that's it!! "()" was missing....